# Combined value from multiple models

Tags: python, django

I want to display combined fields in a template. Precisely, I want to calculate profit from one day (Bill.sold_amount X Item.price).

I can display prices for all the objects, but I can't select that one, which concerns specific item.

Models:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)

class Bill(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    sold_amount = models.IntegerField()
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
```

Views:

```
class SView(ListView):
    template_name = 'app/s_list.html'
    # bills = Bill.objects.all().filter(date__contains=datetime.date(2015, 9, 21))
    model = Item
    context_object_name = 'items'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['bills'] = Bill.objects.all()
        return context
```

Template:

```
{% for bill in bills  %}
    Date: {{ bill.date }}, Item: {{ bill.item }}, Amount {{ bill.sold_amount }}, Value ???? <br>

    {%  for item in items %}
       {{  item.name }} {{item.price}} ?? but only for item related with bill <br>
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You can calculate that in your view. A recommendation tho, save the total amount for your bill in your model, because if the items change their price at a later date, your bill will show an incorrect value.

Comment: You can abuse widthratio to do multiplication in django..
`Value {% widthratio bill.sold_ammount 1 bill.item.price %}`. I've deleted my answer since I also agree with cdvv7788's comment. Also, my answer wouldn't have accounted for discounts

Comment: @cdvv7788 I have also model Storage with fields: amount (Integer) 

Sayse: It doesn't work. On the page I see blank field.

I think, that calculate it in view is a good idea, but how can I transfer this value to template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, don't put calculations in the views, you can put them in your model class:

```
class Bill(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def total_amount(self):
        return self.sold_amount * self.item.price
```

And then, in your template:

```
{% for bill in bills  %}
{{ bill.total_amount }}
{% endfor %}
```

Okey, if you really hope that in the view function, you can:

```
class SView(ListView):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ...
        bills = Bill.objects.all()
        for bill in bills:
            bill.total_amount = bill.sold_amount * bill.item.price

        context['bills'] = bills
        ...
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but if I want to put it in views, how can I do that?

Comment: I wanted to see, how to transfer data from view to template. Context is the answer. Thank You so much for the responses.